# Как изменить элемент вложенного массива в MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Есть документ такого вида:

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "items": [

    {
      "x": "10",
      "val": "123"
    },

    {
      "x": "11",
      "val": "123"
    },

    {
      "x": "12",
      "val": "123"
    }

  ] 
}
```

Мне нужно поменять поле "val" в объекте, где "x": "11". Этот объект в данном случае второй элемент массива, но он может быть любым по счету. Пытаюсь сделать запрос:

```
db.collection("collectionName").update({"name": "a"}, {"..."})
```

Что написать вместо многоточия? Как добраться до элемента с полем "x", равным 11?

Answer (score 5):

```
db.collection("collectionName").update({"items.x" : 11}, {"$set" : {"items.$.val" : "any_value"}})
```